# Creating multi pane screen with tab layout in the left and a fragment in the right

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

So I am making this app where I have a tab layout in my main activity and I have three tabs in that activity. It looks cool when in phone. But when I use a tablet, the items in the tab layout fragments are just too big and shabby. So I thought, 
"Hey lets make this into a two pane screen".

If I didnt have a tab layout, I'd just have the exact same xml in a w820 layout.xml and add a frame layout so that I can check the version of xml the app is using in runtime to make the two pane work

So for example , if this is my layout when I'm in a mobile device,
[image: Image while in mobile device]

I want the layout to be like this in tablets[image: Layout in tablet mode]

So any click event in the tab1 should reflect in the second pane and if i change to tab2 and click on an item, it should reflect in the second pane too.

But I dont know how this logic will work with a tab layout. So if someone can help me with this, I'll be so thankful

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Master/Detail Flow. You can use template provided by Android Studio(File -> New -> Activity -> Master/Detail Flow).

Comment: yeah i know how it works. I just cant make it work when the left pane has a tab layout

Comment: Yes, you can use callback mechanism from fragments to activity. So whenever user tap on any item in TabLayout's fragment you pass that information to Activity via callback and Activity will replace the appropriate detail fragment in 2nd pane(right pane).